# Delete data in Soft delete include Media file

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am using Voyager plugin to do BREAD , it work great but i got 1 problem where i need enable soft delete. It also work great but i want to delete my data in show deleted and media file related to it . anyone have idea on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use eloquent deleted event for any post delete action

```
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::deleted(function($model){
            Storage::delete($model->file_name);
        });
    }
```

You can also make it reusable by defining the event action in a [boot eloquent model trait](https://www.archybold.com/blog/post/booting-eloquent-model-traits)